# How to use Phonetic or Phoneme pronunciation in google text to speech?

Tags: text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I have been trying for a while to get Phonetic or Phoneme pronunciation working with [google's text to speech](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/) but have not managed to get it performing consistently.

I have managed to get limited results from using https://tophonetics.com/
It translated "The cow went mad."  to "ðə kaʊ wɛnt mæd." but the 'the' 'ðə'
was not audible. And when I tried "ðɪs ɪz səm fəˈnɛtɪk tɛkst ˈɪnˌpʊt".

Are there any SSML codes to define phonetic blocks of text, 
that can be this format "D,Is Iz sVm f@n'EtIk t'Ekst 'InpUt" 
can be used instead of  "ðɪs ɪz səm fəˈnɛtɪk tɛkst ˈɪnˌpʊt"
"

Comment: Does Google support it at all? Amazon does https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/polly/latest/dg/supported-ssml.html#phoneme-tag

Comment: Yes, that's how it should work in google too.

Comment: Documentation on Google Cloud for text to speech use of phonemes appears to be limited to a tomato example, however when I test it appears that voice is reading the word "tomato" and is not reading the phoneme for some reason when I alter the word tomato but keep the phoneme <phoneme alphabet="ipa" ph="t&#x259;mei&#x325;&#x27E;ou&#x325;"> tom </phoneme> . Google Cloud's platform doesn't seem to return the voice for the phoneme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the SSML tag `<phoneme>` that serves your purpose.

Unfortunately, it's currently not supported in Google Cloud Text-to-speech. The available subset of SSML tags for Google Cloud is listed in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/ssml). The `<phoneme>` tag is not in this list. An experiment using Google Cloud's [text-to-speech-demo](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech#section-2) confirms that the phonemes are ignored. The content of the tag is being read as ordinary text, as has already been remarked by @Trevor in the comments.

The `<phoneme>` tag is, however, being supported by Microsoft Azure Text-to-Speech and Amazon Polly. In both cases, the available phonemes are limited to those available in the language being used (see [here for Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-ssml-phonetic-sets?tabs=en-US) and [here for Polly](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/ref-phoneme-tables-shell.html)). The Azure documentation isn't 100% clear about the exclusion of out-of-language phonemes, but practical experiments with the [Azure Text-to-Speech demo](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/text-to-speech/#features) confirm that they're not working properly. In some cases, they at least seem to be replaced by the nearest available equivalent in the language used.

Being restricted to the phonemes of one language severely limits the usefulness of the phonemes tag. E.g., you can't used the feature to embed correctly pronounced content in a second language, as the second language will usually have some phonemes that are not available in the first language. Concrete language pairs in which each language has some phonemes that are not available in the other one are English/German, Spanish/German, English/Spanish.

Answer (score 4):

Google Text-to-Speech supports the `<phoneme>` tag since at least spring 2021.

However, there are a lot of potential gotchas to overcome:

- The [demo page](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech#section-2) filters out `<phoneme>` tags on the client side before they even reach the API. (It does the same with the `<voice>` tag as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66712081/39946))
- As with Microsoft Azure Text-to-speech (see the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63885729/39946) for details), each language only supports a [limited set of phonemes](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/phonemes) ("letters") that can be used.
- If you use an unsupported one, the phoneme tag is completely ignored without any warning. So the official example `<phoneme alphabet="ipa" ph="ˌmænɪˈtoʊbə">manitoba</phoneme>` does not work with any English variant but `en-US`, since all others lack the `"o"` or `"oʊ"` phoneme.
- It's unclear if you need to use the `v1beta1` API (which I can confirm is working) or if version `v1` is also ok.

Comment: Is there a way to find out which Google TTS voices work with the `<phoneme>` tag?

Comment: @Lance I couldn't test it, but the documentation appears as if `<phoneme>` supports depends on the language and region, but not on the specific voice. See https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/phonemes This information is not available via the `voices.list` API.