# How to access Google text-to-speech beta features (March 1, 2021 release)

Tags: beta, google-text-to-speech

On March 1, 2021, [Google Text-to-speech released beta features](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/release-notes), including support for the ssml `<voice>` tag with `name` or `lang` attributes.

I'm hoping to use these beta features, but I can't figure out what channel they were released to or how to access them. I haven't found any breadcrumbs in the documentation that would lead me to them.

I noticed that on the [TTS product home page](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech), the demo feature uses `v1beta1`, but doesn't support the `<voice>` tag.
[Screenshot of json from TTS demo stripping out the voice tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzU8q.png)

That is, for the ssml:

```
<speak>
Blah Blah English Text. <voice name="ko-KR-Wavenet-D"> Blah Blah Korean Text.</voice> <break time="400ms" /> Blah Blah English Text.
</speak>
```

the demo shows the following json request body:

```
{
  "audioConfig": {
    "audioEncoding": "LINEAR16",
    "pitch": 0,
    "speakingRate": 1
  },
  "input": {
    "ssml": "<speak> Blah Blah English Text. Blah Blah Korean Text. <break time=\"400ms\" /> Blah Blah English Text. </speak>"
  },
  "voice": {
    "languageCode": "en-US",
    "name": "en-US-Wavenet-D"
  }
}
```

**What we've tried**
In our own script using the google text-to-speech api to generate audio from a csv cue sheet, we've historically used the general release. The script still works when we change to `v1beta1`, but the `<voice>` tag still doesn't function. We're using the npm package symlinked to [nodejs-text-to-speech](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-text-to-speech) master.

Our script uses:
`const textToSpeech = require('@google-cloud/text-to-speech');` and
the general release `const client = new textToSpeech.TextToSpeechClient();`

We've been trying to access the March 1 beta features with
`const client = new textToSpeech.v1beta1.TextToSpeechClient();`

Comment: Did you happen to figure it out?

Comment: @JoshuaCrowley Nope -- any ideas? We had to move on to higher priorities some time ago, but still hoping to get some clues and figure this out.

Comment: I have a similar issue with the `<phoneme>` tag which should be supported since v1beta1. While investigating my issue, I tried your example text in the TTS demo page and in my own, java-based client. Both didn't work. BUT: when I added the opening `<speak>` tag, which is missing in your example, it worked in my client. Still does not work with the demo page, though. Can you try your client again with the opening tag?

Comment: @LenaSchimmel That was a typo on my part in the OP, but in the actual SSML we're using, I have the opening `<speak>` tag. I just tried again using our script, and it's still not working.

In your java-based client, you were able to get two different voices using the `<voice>` tag?

Comment: Yes, in my Java-based client, the SSML example from your post and the SSML example from the new post by @Sandeep-Mohanty work.

Answer (score 2):

According to the release notes of Text-to-Speech API the `<voice>` tag is working as expected. I tried replicating the scenario on my end using **Node.js client library** and it is working as expected.

The document of [SSML](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/ssml#voice) says the `<voice>` **tag allows you to use more than one voice in a single SSML request.** In my code I have used the default voice as English Male and for the other voice I have used the `<voice name="hi-IN-Wavenet-D">` which is a female voice and I am getting two different voices in my output.mp3 file.

You can refer to the below Node.js code and output audio file.

**tts1.js**

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const textToSpeech = require('@google-cloud/text-to-speech');
// Import other required libraries
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');
// Creates a client
const client = new textToSpeech.v1beta1.TextToSpeechClient();
async function quickStart() {
 // The text to synthesize


 const ssml =  '<speak>And then she asked, <voice name="en-IN-Wavenet-D"> where were you yesterday </voice><break time="250ms"/> in her sweet and gentle voice.</speak>'

 // Construct the request
 const request = {
   input: {ssml: ssml},
   // Select the language and SSML voice gender (optional)
   voice: {languageCode: 'en-US', ssmlGender: 'NEUTRAL'},
   // select the type of audio encoding
   audioConfig: {audioEncoding: 'MP3'},
 };

 // Performs the text-to-speech request
 const [response] = await client.synthesizeSpeech(request);
 // Write the binary audio content to a local file
 const writeFile = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);
 await writeFile('output.mp3', response.audioContent, 'binary');
 console.log('Audio content written to file: output.mp3');
}
quickStart();
```

**Output mp3 file :** [output1 (using v1beta1)](https://github.com/sandy0298/text-to-speech/blob/main/output%20(beta1).mp3)

I have also tried without using the **v1beta1 version** in node.js and it is working fine.

**tts2.js:**

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const textToSpeech = require('@google-cloud/text-to-speech');

// Import other required libraries
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');
// Creates a client
const client = new textToSpeech.TextToSpeechClient();
async function quickStart() {
 // The text to synthesize


 const ssml =  '<speak>And then she asked, <voice name="en-IN-Wavenet-D"> where were you yesterday </voice><break time="250ms"/> in her sweet and gentle voice.</speak>'

 // Construct the request
 const request = {
   input: {ssml: ssml},
   // Select the language and SSML voice gender (optional)
   voice: {languageCode: 'en-US', ssmlGender: 'NEUTRAL'},
   // select the type of audio encoding
   audioConfig: {audioEncoding: 'MP3'},
 };

 // Performs the text-to-speech request
 const [response] = await client.synthesizeSpeech(request);
 // Write the binary audio content to a local file
 const writeFile = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);
 await writeFile('output.mp3', response.audioContent, 'binary');
 console.log('Audio content written to file: output.mp3');
}
quickStart();
```

**Output mp3 file :** [output (without v1beta1 version)](https://github.com/sandy0298/text-to-speech/blob/main/output%20(normal).mp3)

Apart from this, I would like to inform you that I have also tried using the **Python client library** and it is also working as expected.

**file1.py**

```
from google.cloud import texttospeech

# Instantiates a client
client = texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient()

# Set the text input to be synthesized
synthesis_input = texttospeech.SynthesisInput(
  
 ssml=  '<speak>And then she asked, <voice name="en-IN-Wavenet-D"> where were you yesterday</voice><break time="250ms"/> in her sweet and gentle voice.</speak>'
    )

# Build the voice request, select the language code ("en-US") and the ssml
# voice gender ("neutral")
voice = texttospeech.VoiceSelectionParams(
   language_code="en-US", ssml_gender=texttospeech.SsmlVoiceGender.NEUTRAL
)

# Select the type of audio file you want returned
audio_config = texttospeech.AudioConfig(
   audio_encoding=texttospeech.AudioEncoding.MP3
)

# Perform the text-to-speech request on the text input with the selected
# voice parameters and audio file type
response = client.synthesize_speech(
   input=synthesis_input, voice=voice, audio_config=audio_config
)

# The response's audio_content is binary.
with open("output.mp3", "wb") as out:
   # Write the response to the output file.
   out.write(response.audio_content)
   print('Audio content written to file "output.mp3"')
```

**output file :** [output (using Python)](https://github.com/sandy0298/text-to-speech/blob/main/output%20(using%20python).mp3)

Answer (score 0):

Google cloud npm package I'm trying to use the FEMALE voice but its always come with NEUTRAL voice

```html
export async function quickStart(text) {
   
    const request = {
        input: { text: text },
        // Select the language and SSML voice gender (optional)
        voice: { languageCode: 'en-US', ssmlGender: 'FEMALE' },
        // select the type of audio encoding
        audioConfig: { audioEncoding: 'MP3' },
    };

    
    const [response] = await client.synthesizeSpeech(request);
    console.log(response);
    return response;
    
}
```